Intune Script not Remediating
We have a short script to detect a file related to a Webmproject Libwebp vulnerability to delete the folder it is not needed by any software we use.
Machines that are confirmed to have the path C:\Windows\Installer\Razer are showing as "no issues" even though the remediation script should be running, exit 1 for the presence of the folder. Any ideas why this script isn't moving to remediation?
The detection script:
$folderPath = "C:\Windows\Installer\Razer"

# Check if the folder exists
if (Test-Path $folderPath) {
    Write-Output "Detected: $folderPath exists"
    exit 1
}
else {
    Write-Output "Not detected: $folderPath does not exist"
    exit 0
} 


A script should exit with zero when successful and exit with non zero when fails.  Your code is backwards.  Where is the remediation code?  You are exiting the script whether you pass or fail.

From what I have been able to ascertain, if Intune is given an exit code of 0, it will NOT run the remediation script, if it finds the exit code is 1, this will trigger the next script to run. I suppose I could be misunderstanding. The remediation script is a separate script since I'm doing this in Intune.

The script (although it has never run) is:
`# Specify the folder path
$folderPath = "C:\Windows\Installer\Razer"
Check if the folder exists
if (Test-Path $folderPath) {
Try to remove the folder and catch any errors
try {
   Remove-Item -Path $folderPath -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Stop
   Write-Output "Folder has been successfully deleted."

}
catch {
Write-Output "An error occurred: $_"
}
}
else {
Write-Output "Folder does not exist."
}`

I think you have a permission issue.  Because you do not have the correct permission "Folder does not exist" gets displayed even though the folder does exist.

The Script looks okay. As jdweng mentioned, this might be a permission issue. Have you tried to validate if this is a permission issue? Also, Kindly look at the best practices listed in this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/fundamentals/remediations
